# How to change Drupal's default login error text

Tags: users

I have tried using this code -

```
     */
    function customform_demo_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
     global $user;

      if ($form_id == 'user_login'); {
        if (!$user->uid) { 
            array_unshift($form['#validate'],'customform_demo_user_login_form_validate');
        }else{
        drupal_get_messages();
        }   
      }

}

function customform_demo_user_login_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message('Your username or password was not recognized. <a class="login_link" href="/user/password">Click here to reset your password.</a>', 'status');
}
```

but can't get the message in the default format.

Comment: You should use [form_set_error()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7), inside the form validate instead of plain `drupal_set_message`.

Comment: Please edit your code first, which has been suggested in the answer..

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you shouldn't have a semi-colon after your if condition.

```
 if ($form_id == 'user_login'); {}
```

Does removing that have any effect?

Comment: None at all. 
Just trying to replicate the "form_set_error" text format.